# Non-type template parameter with template parameter pack

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates, non-type-template-parameter

I am checking the validity of a string whose valid values are known at compile time. I have the following simplified code snippet:

```cpp
#include <cassert>
#include <string>

template <char const* const _Rhs, char const* const _Rhs2,
          char const* const _Rhs3>
bool IsValid(std::string const& _Lhs) {
    return _Rhs == _Lhs or _Rhs2 == _Lhs or _Rhs3 == _Lhs;
}

template <char const* const _Rhs, char const* const _Rhs2>
bool IsValid(std::string const& _Lhs) {
    return _Rhs == _Lhs or _Rhs2 == _Lhs;
}

template <char const* const _Rhs>
bool IsValid(std::string const& _Lhs) {
    return _Rhs == _Lhs;
}

static const char record[] = "record";
static const char replay[] = "replay";
static const char idle[] = "idle";

int main() {
    assert((IsValid<record>("record")));
    assert((IsValid<record, replay>("replay")));
    assert((IsValid<record, replay, idle>("idle")));
    assert((not IsValid<record, replay, idle>("unknown")));
}
```

Is there a way I could **generalize** the *IsValid* function to take an arbitrary number of template parameters?

Something like:

```cpp
template <char const* const _Rhs, typename... Args>
bool IsValid(std::string const& _Lhs) {
    return _Rhs == _Lhs or IsValid<Args...>(_Lhs);
}
```

Comment: Are you restricted to a 11 year old dialect of C++ as your tags indicate?  Why, exactly, are you passing the strings as template parameters?  (I get you know them at compile time; but is there a requirement that they are template parameters?)  What level of freedom do you have in syntax; must  it be *exactly* `IsValid<A,B,C,D,E,F>` where `A` through `F` are the names of strings, or can it be different?  (Each of these questions rules in and out a different set of answers; there are many, many solutions to your problem)

Comment: Right, c++11. It was meant to follow the syntax of the existing *IsValid<\*>(x)* functions in my code which are taking some other numeral template parameters. Just making sure I am not missing some nice solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
template<char const* str>
struct str_t {
  static const char* string = str;
};
bool IsValidImpl(std::string const& str) {
  return false;
}
template<class String, class...Strings>
bool IsValidImpl(std::string const& str, String, Strings... strings) {
  return (str == String::string) || IsValidImpl( str, strings... );
}
template<class...Strings>
bool IsValid(std::string const& str) {
  return IsValidImpl(str, Strings{}...);
}

assert((IsValid<str_t<record> >("record")));
assert((IsValid<str_t<record>, str_t<replay> >("replay")));
assert((IsValid<str_t<record>, str_t<replay>, str_t<idle> >("idle")));
assert((not IsValid<str_t<record>, str_t<replay>, str_t<idle> >("unknown")));
```

there are much cleaner ways to do this in [c++14](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b14) [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17) and [c++20](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b20), but this is a [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11) solution as required.

Comment: Interesting solution, thanks. ``bool IsValidImpl(std::string const& str) {return true;}`` should return false.